# Javascript regular expression to validate phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help me how to validate the phone number with the following conditions

1. '+' is an optional character.
2. it should allow only numbers from 0-9
3. length no limitations.

sample:

- 98764121 (true)
- +92883944 (true)
- 799e9900 (false)

Comment: How many digits at least?

Comment: @nissimabehcera There is no limitation. Minimum should be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex : `^[+]?[0-9]{1,}$`

^: start of the line

[+]? : the char '+' 0 or 1 time

[0-9]: only digits

{1,}: 1 (digit) at least to infinite

$: end of line

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @nissim abehcera answer & the actual question expected answer, If we want validation for phone number should start with any specific number you can try following regex ^[+]?[0-9]{1,}$ and below example adds additional validation for number starts only with 9 or +9

```
^[\+]?[9]{1}[0-9]{1,}$

^         - #Match the beginning of the string 
[\+]?[9]  - #Should starts with 9 or +9
[0-9]     - #Match the digits(0 to 9)
{1,}      - #Should contain one digit
$         - #Match the end of the string
```

Comment: I think you should ask this in the code review forum and not here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```js
const isPhoneNumber = (number) => {
    return new RegExp(/^\+?[0-9]+$/).test(number)
}

console.log(isPhoneNumber('98764121'));
console.log(isPhoneNumber('+92883944'));
console.log(isPhoneNumber('799e9900'));
console.log(isPhoneNumber('+'));
console.log(isPhoneNumber('+123'));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use parseInt() for the question.

parseInt(+98764121); //98764121

parseInt(799e9900); //NaN

parseInt(98764121); //98764121

and check the result with isNaN()